# center ul inside a div along with other floating ul

Tags: html, css

I have a div that contains two ul. I'd like to position the first ul on he right and the second ul on the center.
I cannot use absolute positioning since it makes me other problems in nested elements and in mobile view.

This is what I've done:

```
<div class="w">
    <ul class="right"><li>a very very very long text</li></ul>
    <ul class="center"><li>center</li></ul>
</div>

.w {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

.right {
    float: right;
}

.center {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

you can see jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mF7XR/

The problem is that the centered ul is aligned to the middle between the left and the start of the right ul (see the example). Therefore it is not correctly centered. How can I center correct the second ul?

Comment: you can set it right by doing `.right {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
}`. In my opinion, going with position absolute is correct. It will not invoke any issues later as this `ul` has support from other `ul` in layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the Width of centered elements then only you could get what you want. You could also define the margin as follows...
margin: 0 {number greater than right floated element}px 0 {number greater than left floated element here you have only two elements so place here 0}px;

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether you are good to go with javascript. Anyway, I did some work on it. Please have a look.

**javascript**

```
//Added Id to ul.center as "center"
function resize(){
  var width = document.body.offsetWidth;
  var center = document.getElementById('center');
  center.style.marginLeft = (width/2) - (center.offsetWidth/2);
}
//Call the above function on "resize" and "load" events.
```

---

**CSS**

```
.center {
   display: inline-block;
   float:left;
}
```

**[Working Bin](http://jsbin.com/ukazad/2/edit)**

Comment: Good idea but too much JS.. +1

Comment: @Naor I think it is not achievable without using JS or positioning. (maybe there are any css3 properties). or else you may need to redesign it. Anyway thanks for +1 though. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about `position:relative`? Then you can position it anywhere without it causing problems in nested elements and mobile view.

http://jsfiddle.net/mF7XR/4/

Comment: Mine and Jose's answer do the same thing.Choose whichever you like.Cheers!

Comment: But what should I do with the bottom:20px? I never can be sure what is the height of the first / second ul..

Comment: @Naor you are right. In that case, I think you should use javascript or jQuery. Calculate the width of the `.right` and **add** the half of that width to the `margin-left` of the `.center`. Your `ul.center` will come to center. (add the same javascript function on both resize and load events to work properly)

Comment: Yes that's true,you'll have to do something else then. @Mr_Green Good solution!

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses no absolute positioning. Tested on Win/Chrome.

Change the `.center` to

```
.center {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    top: -20px; /* move up */
}
```

and add this rule

```
.center li {
    float: none;
}
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mF7XR/3/)**

---

**Update**

If your content is not known, then you need JS (or jQuery) to set the offset relative position.

Initially I thought about using a different markup, but your restriction on absolute positioning pretty much kills this idea.

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mF7XR/5/)**

It would be interesting to know why you cannot use absolute position. Maybe the root of your problem lies there.

Comment: See the comment I wrote to @Ronophobia.

Comment: I can't use absolute positioning since tomorrow we might decide that the "center" ul should be right in certain circumstances. If the "right" class has absolute positioning the two uls with absolute positioning will be one on top of the other. float: right solves this.

Comment: @Naor Did my second jsFiddle helped you?